# browser compatibility issue with javascript image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, browser

```
$j('#images').bind('change', function() {
   var abcd=$j('#images')[0].value;
   var image_size_r=abcd.filesize/1024/1024;
   var imp=parseFloat(image_size_r);
   alert(imp);
});
```

Hi all this one works in mozilla but doesn't work for chrome or IE. Any idea why??? thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant bit of HTML as well?

Comment: What do you intend to do? The `onchange` event does not trigger for `<img>` elements. Use the `onload` event instead. And neither the `value` nor `filesize` property is supported for `<img>`.

Comment: Do your developer tools indicate an error?

Comment: paste debugger details in chrome too.